# Azure functions as job scheduler application

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am planning to move our on-premise scheduler windows service application to azure. 
This application uses Quartz .NET to schedule jobs. We have around 1000 jobs that are running under this application. 90% of the jobs access SQL server database.

I am planning to use azure functions to trigger jobs and I do not want to create 1000 function apps for each job.

I will create a function app with timer trigger and a queue trigger. Timer trigger runs every minute and fetches and queues active jobs from database and Queue trigger function then run those queued jobs.

I would like to know if this an reliable approach? If not are there any other options?

Comment: did you manage to achieve this via Triggers? I'm having like same issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used durable functions with fanout architecture.

Comment: I'm not sure how you accomplished this with azure functions. Is there any code you can share?